# How to solve 404 page using Sitecore MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore 7. For a project I'm using the MVC functionality. I will first explain what I did. I

1. Created a new MVC3 project with deploy to File System (with reference to `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` and `Sitecore.Mvc.dll, Sitecore.Mvc.config` added);
2. Created a new layout in the MVC3 project, named `Main.cshtml`;
3. Created a new layout in Sitecore and path configured: `/Views/Main.cshtml` (when I click on the Grid designer the layout shows up);
4. Configured layout Main on the Home item as Layout;
5. Published the whole site;
6. Clicked on the Home-item: `Presentation > Preview`.

The problem: an 404 error occured, the page cannot be found. Does anyone know how i could solve the 404 problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What errors are listed in your log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It seems to be caused by a non correct web.config file. I have fixed it by using the Sitecore installer. After installation, I have the web.config file copied to my project.

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer if you are happy that the issue is now resolved.